# SQL Server queries with mssql crashing node app

Tags: sql-server, node.js

I have been developing a node.js app that connects to a SQL Server database using the mssql module but I have run into a wall.

Basically, mssql seems to have some kind of bug where it simply crashes the app if the results of a query of any kind returns a certain number of records. Nothing too heavy. I'm talking about 50 to 100 records!

This is not query specific either. It is happening on ALL my queries, no matter what the results are.

The queries run fine if I limit them to return 10, 20, 40 records (using "SELECT TOP x ..."), but as soon as I increase the limit to a larger number of records, the app simply crashes without a single error message. No exceptions. Nothing.

The actual number of records where this starts to happen varies from query to query. It looks as if mssql has either a bug or a by-design limitation that affects the amount of data that it can return.

Am I missing something? Is there I setting I should be changing to avoid this? Alternatively, is there any other npm that I could use to connect to SQL Server?

Needless to say, this is a show-stopper for me. Should I abandon node.js altogether?

The point is, that if I cannot find a proper way to connect to SQL Server, then I will not be able to use node.js for this app and will have to switch to something else.

Thank you!

**UPDATE 1**

Here is part of the code that is causing this issue:

```
// Basic modules
var express = require("express");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");

// Custom modules
var settings = require("./lib/settings.js").GetSettings();

var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use('/', express.static(__dirname + "/public"));

/***************************************************************************************************************/
// Routes

app.get("/GetBrands", function(req, res) {
    var sql = require('mssql');

    var config = {
        user: settings.DatabaseConfiguration.user,
        password: settings.DatabaseConfiguration.password,
        server: settings.DatabaseConfiguration.server,
        database: settings.DatabaseConfiguration.database
    };

    var cmd = "SELECT TOP 5 * FROM Brands WHERE Status = 'a'";

    var connection = new sql.Connection(config, function(err) {
        // ... error checks
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }

        // Query

        var request = new sql.Request(connection); // or: var request = connection.request();
        request.verbose = true;

        request.query(cmd, function(err, recordset) {
            // ... error checks
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }

            console.log(recordset);

            connection.close();
        });
    });
});


/***************************************************************************************************************/

// Enable the port listening.
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8050);
```

If I change the the SQL statement that says "SELECT TOP 5 * ..." to a bigger number, like 60, 80 or 100, the app crashes. Also, the response is simply the name of each brand and an ID. Nothing too complicated or heavy.

**UPDATE 2:**

These are the steps I am following which always crash the app:

1. Run the app by typing in command-line: node app.js
2. In a web browser, go to http://localhost:8050/GetBrands. The very first time, I get the results just fine. No crashes.
3. Run it a second time. The app crashes. Every time.

I also discovered something else. I am using WebStorm for editing the code. If I start the debugger from there, I get no crashes, no issues whatsoever. The app works just as it should. It only crashes when I run it directly from command-line, or from WebStorm without the debugger listening... how crazy is this??

I tried applying the same command-line parameters that the WebStorm debugger uses but it made no difference.

I Hope somebody can shed some light soon because I am very close to dropping node.js altogether for this project thanks to this.

I am OK with switching to use a different SQL Server npm package, but which one then? I already tried mssql, node-sqlserver-unofficial and tedious, they all have the same issue so I am guessing that it is a problem with TDS.

Comment: I kinda doubt this is a problem with node specifically, if anything it's a problem with the connector or the server it is connecting to. Can you show the [simple node.js app](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that you're testing this problem with?

Comment: How does the app crash? Is there an error message?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. No error messages at all. It simply stops the node app without any kind of message.

Answer (score 0):

By using the streaming interface, you can reduce your overhead significantly, and allow for better handling of very large query results.  I use the streaming interface, for example with piping to export files (csv and xml).

With a relatively simple test, I'm able to crash node itself loading a *very* large array with 36-character strings (generated with `uuid.v4()`), at it happens for me around 1GB of use.  My guess is there's a hard limit for a number of references allowed in in a running instance.